# Combining dynamic binding and the unmanaged constraint in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, constraints, unsafe, overload-resolution

## Premise:

Let's take the following code sample:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static unsafe void f(StringComparison c)
    {
        // One overload used to pin the handle to the memory on the GC Heap and do unsafe stuff.
        // Can be generic as well, but I chose to simplify the example for better clarity.
    }

    public static void f(string c)
    {
        // Another overload just to describe the problem.
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Returns an instance of StringComparison at runtime with the compile-time type of object.
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StringComparison));

        // Resolves to f(StringComparison) and everything works as expected.
        f(c);
    }
}
```

Here the correct overload of `f` is called successfully with a `dynamic` binding.

---

When I add the `unmanaged` constraint into the mix with generics as follows (MCVE):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static unsafe void f<T>(T v) where T : unmanaged
    {
        // Unsafe generic method needed to handle primitive types and enums (including user defined ones).
        // Unsafe because of the same reason in the first sample.
    }

    public static void f(string s)
    {
        // Another overload just to describe the problem.
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        // Returns an instance of StringComparison at runtime with the compile-time type of object.
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StringComparison));

        // Oops! We have an error!
        // error CS8377: The type 'dynamic' must be a non-nullable value type,
        // along with all fields at any level of nesting,
        // in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Program.f<T>(T)'
        f(c);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The overload `f(string)` is present only for illustrating the problem. Any incompatible type that forces the `f<T>(T)` overload to be chosen can work as well.
2. `Activator.CreateInstance` is also present to illustrate a function that returns an instance of the correct type (an `enum` in this case) at runtime.

I'm not familiar with the mechanics `dynamic` uses to perform overload resolution at runtime, but [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) suggests that:

> `dynamic` is assumed to support any operation.

Since the first sample works (`dynamic` is able to bind to an `enum`, satisfying the `unmanaged` constraint which is **NOT** explicitly specified), I expected the second one to also work.

## Questions:

1. Is this behaviour expected or is it a bug? If it is expected, please explain why.
2. Are there any workarounds to call the generic `f<T>(T)` overload without using reflection?